# Cannot fetch the current provider injected by metamask into a constant

Tags: reactjs, blockchain

I created a ReactApp.After creation, within my src folder I created my own folder called web3.js. Within that, I extracted the current provider installed by metamask on the chrome browser and tried to store that provider to a constant. Unfortunately, when I run the app, it provides me a type error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentProvider' of undefined"

I have tried googling this error and cannot figure out the solution to fix this

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);

export default web3;
```

**Expected**: When i run the app, it should not show the type error

**Actual**: When i run the app, type-error displayed

Images:
[React-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf423.png)
[React error when i run the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7GlA.png)

Comment: This looks like a similar issue and might solve your problem: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32551/web3-currentprovider-is-undefined-with-metamask

Comment: Shall I write: var web3;   window.web3= new Web3(web3.currentProvider). Not sure if I completely understand the reply to it

Comment: What is your output if you remove const web3 = new Web3(...); and simply console.log(web3); ? Because it looks like it's already defined.

Comment: The idea is to get the current provider injected by metamask and assign it to a constant. I have tried what you recommended as a step to troubleshoot but appears some other error is encountered

Answer (score 0):

Without more details or code about how you're

> "extracting the current provider"

there's only so much to troubleshoot.

That being said, I would guess that your problem is a race condition between when Metamask is injecting web3 and when your code snippet above is being executed.

```
MetaMask Injection ================== web3 inject! =====


Your Code          ======= exec * ======================
                   * const web3 = window.web3 
                   (but web3 not injected yet)
```

It might be helpful to consult the [MetaMask FAQ Docs](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check):

> MetaMask injects web3 object and convenience Web3.js library into the javascript context. Look for this before using your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / read-only / fail)
>
> Note that the environmental web3 check is wrapped in a window.addEventListener('load', ...) handler. **This approach avoids race conditions with web3 injection timing.**

Most DApp detect and set web3 with a listener similar to something below.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }

  // Now you can start your app & access web3 freely:
  startApp()
})
```

Alternatively, since you're using React, I'd recommend checking out the [Truffle React Box](https://truffleframework.com/boxes) which has a [built in method](https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box/blob/master/client/src/utils/getWeb3.js) for fetching web3 which prevents the race condition

Answer (score 0):

you can use [infura](https://infura.io/) alternative for metamask  for reading information from contract

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.